# Pull out values in a dataframe column corresponding to numbers in a pandas.series - and transfer to new series

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series and a pandas dataframe. The pandas dataframe has two columns, ‘a’ and ‘b’
For every number in the pandas series, I need find the closest number in column ‘b’ of the dataframe but place the corresponding value in column ‘a’ into a new series.

I’ve been trying to use the iloc and index.get_loc functions to try find the right row in the dataframe but I’ve had no success.

Example:

```
Series = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Dataframe =

‘a’     ‘b’
1   0
4   3
5   2
6   1
8   5
9   4

New_series = 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8
```

The order of the first series needs to be maintained in the new_series.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for ya

`for num in old_series:
    idx = df[df['b'] == num].index
    new_series = new_series.append(df.loc[idx,'a'])`

Comment: Thanks, man! I'm getting an error, too many indexers. The the datframe has many more columns than the series, which I think may be the problem?

Comment: @BioProg are you able to show the output of ur dataframe columns